# NO SIM after installed update. Fixable?

Tags: lumia

Today I got Nokia 925 after waiting long time (T-Mobile USA).
I cut my old SIM, installed, all worked great.

Then I setup phone, everything worked great.

Installed Windows update on phone. Phone rebooted and NO SIM... I thought maybe SIM card was damaged. Installed (using adapter) into old phone and all is well, working great.

Installing sim card into Nokia 925 - NO SIM.

Is it fixable or I should take it back to store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device was fine. Didn't like how I cut SIM card. They made me a new card and all is well. Store rep said that new phones don't like cut SIM's, they have to be cut just perfect and many times they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a fault with the device, so take it back for a warranty swap.